# how transfer data like images , location (latitude and longitude), and comment to myLocal Server and php site?

Tags: php, android, image

```
{

  public class Camera1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,LocationListener {
        LocationManager lm;

Button btnTackPic;
ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;
Bitmap bitMap;
static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,60000,5.0f,this);

    // Get reference to views


    btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakePic);
    ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);

    // add onclick listener to the button
    btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(this);

}

// on button "btnTackPic" is clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // start camera activity
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){
        // get bundle
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        // get bitmap
        bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitMap);

    }

}

// method to check if you have a Camera
private boolean hasCamera(){
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
}

// method to check you have Camera Apps
private boolean hasDefualtCameraApp(String action){
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    return list.size() > 0;

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    tv.setText("the latitude is  "+ location.getLatitude()+ "\n"+"the longitude is  "+location.getLongitude());


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

}}
```

I have developed a application in android that I wanna transfer data "images , location (latitude and longitude), and comment" between it and a server.

Answer (score 0):

```
     - 

        HashMap<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
                           paramMap.put("user_id", user_id);
                           paramMap.put("latitude","10");
                           paramMap.put("longitude","70");

                           RequestParams params = new RequestParams(paramMap);
                           try {
                               params.put("image", user_image);
                           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                               Log.d("FNF", ":->" + e.toString());
                           }

          AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
             client.post(url,params,ResponseHandler(){

          //Overridden Methods
      }
  );
```

**Here I am using http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ client for networking.**

Add this dependency in your gradle build file. You can bundle this in a function and call it whenever your app should post data to server.